# Trouble launching custom utility on RasPi via cmd using Process.Start

Tags: c#, ssh, cmd

This is my first question on here, so bear with me.

I'm working on a winforms GUI in C# that communicates with a RasPi running test hardware. Most of that works fine, but something new I was asked to add doesn't yet.

So, one of the forms has a button that opens another form which lets us toggle specific bits on various ICs on the hardware. Someone wrote a utility on the RasPi which displays the state of those bits in a SSH window (usually PuTTy, but also works through cmd->ssh in Win10).

(For anyone who cares, we're trying to move away from PuTTy (or any other 3rd party tool) for this so we don't have to figure out packaging it into our installer. Some of our clients have no networks beyond their PC and the test hardware.)

[SSH Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usn8X.png)

[Utility, opened from File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmFcq.png)

What I was asked to do is open this utility alongside the second form. Sounds simple enough, but I can't figure out how to get it working.

I have a .cmd in a folder on my desktop that launches the utility just fine when I click to run. All it has in it is "ssh -t semitek@{ip} /usr/semitekutil/outs".

In my GUI (Running through VS 2019, with the project on a company server), I tried pointing it to that cmd file like this:

```
outs.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\jfink\Desktop\4xDebugLEDs\4xPiOuts_NoPutty.cmd";
outs.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Default\Desktop\4xDebugLEDs\";
outs.Start();
```

And this:

```
outs.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
outs.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\Default\Desktop\";
outs.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
outs.StartInfo.Arguments = "ssh -t semitek@" + df.IPaddr + " /usr/semitekutil/outs";
outs.Start();
```

Both of which give me this:

[Starting through GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlDOR.jpg)

[Utility started through GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehr0p.png)

I've also tried:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "ssh -t semitek@192.168.50.102 /usr/semitekutil/outs");
```

but that doesn't execute the argument.

[Process.Start() with args](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27Yu6.png)

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? I don't understand why clicking the cmd in File Explorer works just fine, but calling it through the GUI doesn't, nor why the utility displays differently for each access method...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm kind of new to all of this (threading/client-server/etc). Do you have any advice on where to start breaking the parts down? Also, it should probably be noted that we haven't been able to get remote debugging on the RasPi up and running, so if there are issues in the code there, it's much harder to track down.

Comment: ...And my boss just shelved this feature request. I might come back to this later as a learning exercise, or when he changes his mind (again). Thanks for your input so far!